# Why intersection type's values are always assignable to it's member types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

```js
type A = {a: number};
type B = {b: boolean, c: number};
type I = A & B;

let aAndB: I = {
  a: 1,
  b: true,
  c: 2
}

let valueOfA: A = aAndB;  // No Error Here!!!
```

Above when the `valueOfA` is assigned a value of the intersection type of `A` and `B` types, it works well in spite of annotating the variable with type `A` which has a property `a` of type `number` and nothing else. Why this kind of assignment is valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because TypeScript implements structural typing.

This is described in detail in the [TypeScript handbook Type Compatibility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) chapter.

The key aspect of structural typing as it relates to your question:

> The basic rule for TypeScript’s structural type system is that x is compatible with y if y has at least the same members as x.

So, in your case, a variable of type `I` is assignable to a variable of type `A` because `I` satisfies the property requirements of type `A`.