# Enforce strict TypeScript function type alias return type

Tags: typescript

Is there any way to enforce a TypeScript function return type outside of an explicit inline instance?

For example, I want to declare a type alias for a function with a strict return type ([link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8BQVtQJYBMAuKAZ2ACdcA7AcwG4sczLaSB%20Y56mgbQF0GAXwwZQkKACUIwAK7kqJOInGoAFAEooyAHywESBhgDGAewXAoAMxMniU2fMX6VUDVt2YcUctLlV0jF7YBMQA5KEANIFBXKzE-FFBOACGJPiWqelhoVAA9LlQVCZQEOTkJuRQABal0ADuNf7ANT6kVSYyADb4UABGEGzRwoJAA)):

```
type MyType = {
    id: string;
    strings?: string[];
}

type ReturnsMyType = () => MyType;

const foo: ReturnsMyType = () => {
    return {
        id: '',
        strings: [],
        asdfasdf: '' // no error here when there should be?
    }
}
```

TypeScript happily allows me to give my return object the field `asdfasdf` even though it doesn't exist on `MyType`.

Weirdly, TypeScript is definitely doing *some* kind of type checking, because if I fail to give the return object a required property (like `id`) it will indeed complain. But I can add as many arbitrary properties to the object as I want. What gives?

Edit: in response to the helpful comment below, why does the above method behave differently than below:

```
function foo(): MyType {
    return {
        id: '',
        strings: [],
        asdfasdf: '' // DOES give an error
    }
}
```

If it were *only* about structural typings, it seems both approaches would work the same, yet they do not. What else is going on?

Comment: TypeScript implements structural typing, meaning that types are assignable if they have "at least" the required properties. It doesn't prevent assignment when an object has additional properties - see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69040579/81723

Comment: @Sly_cardinal thanks for the info, that doesn't seem to be the entire story though. Why is there a difference between using a function declaration alias vs declaring the return type explicitly inline? For example, `function foo(): MyType {}` gives me the desired type strictness (I cannot return an object with additional properties) just fine. It would seem the structural typing rules would apply to both, and if they do not, then why not?

Comment: There are also [*excess property checks*](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) which only happen in certain circumstances when assigning an object literal to a place that expects a particular type.  Inferred function return types are not one of those circumstances, although there's a longstanding suggestion to change this at [ms/TS#241](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/241) although.